# framed-like boxes across pages [mathspec or biblatex packages]

Tags: boxes, framed

I'm trying to find the code to get boxes like the ones we can enjoy in the mathspec or biblatex user guides. It seems to be based on the listings and framed packages. Here is a working minimal example

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[top=9cm,bottom=10cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\definecolor{boxframe}{rgb}{0.99,0.05,0.05}
\definecolor{boxfill}{rgb}{0.99,0.95,0.95}
\lstdefinestyle{plain}{escapechar={\#}}
\lstnewenvironment{example}[1][]
{\lstset{aboveskip=15pt,xleftmargin=3pt,xrightmargin=3pt,basewidth=0.5em,basicstyle=\normalsize,frame=single,backgroundcolor=\color{boxfill},fillcolor=\color{white},rulecolor=\color{boxframe},framesep=2pt,framerule=0.5pt,style=plain,#1}}{}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\begin{example}
listing
listing
listing
listing
listing
listing
\end{example}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

I'd like to be able to extract the relevant piece of code in the listings package for other purposes but, so far, in vain. I thought it was using the framed package but it is not.

Comment: The source is all available, so you could go digging.  For `biblatex` a lot of the work is done by `ltxdockit.sty`

Comment: it is pretty strange because the `listings guide` mentions the `framed` package but I cannot find where in the code? I think it is the same for `ltxdockit.sty`. I'll go further.

Comment: `listings` is inspired by `fancyvrb` and it makes more sense to use it in a way you already did, define a new environment.

Comment: @Herbert: I'll have a look at `fancyvrb` but I wanted to create a theorem-like environment (title, numbering, labeling similar to `ntheorem` or `thmtools`) based on the frame offered by `listings`. That is why I wanted to extract the code dedicated to the frame. Using `listings` as such could be possible also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `framed.sty`.

Use `listings.sty` and modify its properties.

Together with `fancyvrb.sty` you can create `showexpl.sty`-like environment that can span across multiple pages.

Let me know if you need more info how to do it.

Comment: @Herbert: OK. I will edit my answer. Thanks.